# Can I use an app user's friend public data (id, name, gender) in other app users app context

Tags: facebook

I am developing an app in which I want a user (Alice) to send a list of few of her friends to one of her other friends (Bob). Bob is not a friend of the people on Alice's list. 
The list that will be displayed to Bob will contain only public data that can be queried from facebook by the ids of the friends on the list. Meaning, I will only save the ids of the friends.

Is what I'm planning in accordance with the [Platform Policies](http://developers.facebook.com/policy/#data)? and particularly with sections 2.4:

> A user's friends' data can only be used in the context of the user's experience on your application.

and 2.11:

> You cannot use a user’s friend list outside of your application, even if a user consents to such use, but you can use connections between users who have both connected to your application.

Answer (score 0):

If you provide that information inside your app context I see no problem... Meaning If in your app you sugest the Alice Friends to Bob you'r OK.

It's been done time and time again...

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you may be looking for Facebook's friend suggest dialog, which is part of their API. Facebook will suggest and send a friend request on your behalf.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/friends/